# How to get vdots between equations

Tags: equations, formatting

I was just wondering how to thicken my vdots, but also get them inbetween equations.

I am trying to use vdots to skip some of this derivation. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}     
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
} 

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    &\begin{aligned}
    \mathllap{ L(c; \mathbf{x})} &= \pi(\mathbf{x}|c) 
    \end{aligned}\\
    &\begin{aligned}
     &= \{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n h_{v_i}(x(t_{i-1}),c_{v_i})exp\{-h_0(x(t_{i-1}),c)[t_i-t_{i-1}]\} \\
        &\qquad \times exp\{-h_0(x(t_n),c)[T-t_n]\} \\
    \end{aligned}
    \vdots \\
    &\begin{aligned}
    &= \{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n h_{v_i}(x(t_{i-1}),c_{v_i})\}exp\{-\sum\limits_{i=0}^n h_0(x(t_i),c)[t_{i+1}-t_i]\}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. I do not quite understand what you are trying to do with those `aligned` envs. Is this what you are looking for? I've alsp fixed the `exp`'s and scaled some `\{...\}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}     
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
} 

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{align*}
    L(c; \mathbf{x}) &= \pi(\mathbf{x}|c)
    \\
    &= \Bigl\{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n
    h_{v_i}(x(t_{i-1}),c_{v_i})\exp\{-h_0(x(t_{i-1}),c)[t_i-t_{i-1}]\}
    \\
    &\qquad \times \exp\{-h_0(x(t_n),c)[T-t_n]\}
    \\
    \shortvdotswithin{=} % no \\ after this one
    &= \Bigl\{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n
    h_{v_i}(x(t_{i-1}),c_{v_i})\Bigr\}\exp\Bigl\{-\sum\limits_{i=0}^n
    h_0(x(t_i),c)[t_{i+1}-t_i]\Bigr\}
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @daleif Sorry if mine makes no sense, I was just copying from another example on this sight. I didn't fully understand it though. I was just trying to align all ym equations togehter

Comment: @campa  I works with and without at the start, it is at the end that is a problem. I'll remove it.

Comment: @campa which trick?

Comment: @daleif The starred version calls a macro with a first argument `00`, the unstarred with `01`, and an `\if` discriminates then the two cases. I've never seen/thought of that.

Comment: @campa I think that came from Morten Høgholm. (I think something similar is behind the toggle feature in `etoolbox`)

Comment: er, in the second line, the size of the braces doesn't match.

Comment: @barbarabeeton count the braces, it has no matching end brace, I have no idea what the OP was typesetting, but not scaling that brace looked strange.